# Optimize code for Nth largest element in sorted matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, matrix

I have a code for nth largest element in a sorted matrix (sorted row and column wise increasing order)

I had some problem doing the (findNextElement) part in the code
i.e if the row is exhausted, then go up one row and get the next element in that.

I have managed to do that, but the code looks kind of complex. (My code does work and produces the output correctly) I will post my code here

k is the Kth largest element
m, n are matrix dimensions (right now it just supports NxN matrix but can be modified to support MxN)

```
public int findkthLargestElement(int[][] input, int k, int m, int n) {
    if (m <=1 || n <= 1 || k > m * n) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if (k < m && k < n) {
        i = m - k;
        j = n - k;
    }
    PriorityQueue<Element> maxQueue = new PriorityQueue(m, new Comparator<Element>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Element a, Element b) {
            return b.value - a.value;
        }
    });

    Map<Integer, Integer> colMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int row = i; row < m; row++) {
        Element e = new Element(input[row][n - 1], row, n - 1);
        colMap.put(row, n - 1);
        maxQueue.add(e);
    }
    Element largest = new Element(0, 0, 0);
    for (int l = 0; l < k; l++) {
        largest = maxQueue.poll();
        int row = largest.row;
        colMap.put(row, colMap.get(row) - 1);
        int col = colMap.get(row);
        while (col < j && row > i) {
            row = row - 1;
            colMap.put(row, colMap.get(row) - 1);
            col = Math.max(0, colMap.get(row));
        }

        Element nextLargest = new Element(input[row][Math.max(0, col)], row, Math.max(0, col));
        maxQueue.add(nextLargest);
    }
    return largest.value;

}
```

I need some help in the for loop specifically, please suggest me a better way to accomplish the task.

I have my code running here 
http://ideone.com/wIeZSo

Ok I found a a simple and effective way to make this work, I changed my for loop to ths

```
    for (int l = 0; l < k; l++) {
        largest = maxQueue.poll();
        int row = largest.row;
        colMap.put(row, colMap.get(row) - 1);
        int col = colMap.get(row);
        if (col < j) {
            continue;
        }
        Element nextLargest = new Element(input[row][Math.max(0, col)], row, Math.max(0, col));
        maxQueue.add(nextLargest);
    }
```

If we are exhausted with a column then we do not add anymore items till we reach an element from some other column.

This will also work for matrix which are only sorted row wise but not column wise.

Comment: You should probably explain why the implementation of this method may **not** just be `int i=m*n-1-(k-1);return input[i/n][i%n];`. Most likely because there may be *equal* elements in the matrix...?

Comment: @Marco13 I never thought of the solution you presented! but yes the values can be duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comment: Even if there are duplicate elements, I don't think that it is necessary to use sophisticated data structures like priority queues and maps, or even inner classes. I think it should be possible to simply start at the end of the array, walk to the beginning of the array, and count how often the value changed. Starting with the value "infinity" (or `Integer.MAX_VALUE` here), after the `k`th value change, one has the `k`th largest element.

```
public class KthLargestElementTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        testDistinct();
        testNonDistinct();
        testAllEqual();
    }

    private static void testDistinct()
    {
        System.out.println("testDistinct");
        int[][] input = new int[][] 
        {
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {8, 9, 10, 11},
            {33, 44, 55, 66},
            {99, 150, 170, 200}
        };
        for (int i = 1; i <= 17; i ++) 
        {
            System.out.println(findkthLargestElement(input, i, 4, 4));  
        }
    }

    private static void testNonDistinct()
    {
        System.out.println("testNonDistinct");
        int[][] input = new int[][]
        {
            { 1, 1, 1, 4 },
            { 4, 4, 11, 11 },
            { 11, 11, 66, 66 },
            { 66, 150, 150, 150 } 
        };
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(findkthLargestElement(input, i, 4, 4));
        }
    }    

    private static void testAllEqual()
    {
        System.out.println("testAllEqual");
        int[][] input = new int[][]
        {
            { 4, 4, 4, 4 },
            { 4, 4, 4, 4 },
            { 4, 4, 4, 4 },
            { 4, 4, 4, 4 } 
        };
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(findkthLargestElement(input, i, 4, 4));
        }
    }    

    public static int findkthLargestElement(
        int[][] input, int k, int m, int n) 
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int i=m*n-1;
        int previousValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            int value = input[i/n][i%n];
            if (value < previousValue)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter == k)
            {
                return value;
            }
            previousValue = value;
            i--;
        }
        if (counter == k)
        {
            return input[0][0];
        }
        System.out.println("There are no "+k+" different values!");
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was getting ahead of myself and implementing a K way merge to work on matrix sorted only column wise. eg 
`1,2,3
9,10,11
4,5,6`

Comment: I think your code will break on this      
`int[][] i = {{10, 20, 30, 40},
        {15, 25, 35, 45},
        {24, 29, 37, 48},
        {32, 33, 39, 50}};`

Comment: @jay OK, the last one is not "sorted" in the sense how I understood this. Maybe it's difficult to give a *precise* problem statement and representative test cases, but it may be necessary (at least of one expects a precise and helpful answer)